# Xubuntu 16.04 "Bash: Alias: X: not found"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, alias

I'm trying to create aliases as part of my homework.
Following a guide on how to make aliases on Linux, I did this:

1. Edited ~/.bashrc by adding "alias pwgen="pwgen -y -1 12"" (without the outer quotation marks of course) so writing pwgen would give one 12 character password with at least 1 special character.
2. Did "source ~/.bashrc"

But here's the problem, after the source command the terminal says:

```
Bash: Alias: -y: not found
Bash: Alias: -1: not found
Bash: Alias: 12: not found
```

I tried just writing

```
alias pwgen="pwgen -y -1 12"
```

in the basic Linux terminal, but the outcome was the same.

What did I miss or do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works like a charm on my linux box so the issue may come from elsewhere. Try to use simple quote like this :

```
alias pwgen='pwgen -y -1 12'
```

Comment: A simple quote worked. For some reason, none of my (desktop or laptop) keyboards have the function to write a simple quotation mark in a virtual machine running Xubuntu.